# Python CSV Iterator within Iterator

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I am currently trying to iterate over a csv within an existing iterator. The data within the csv is similar to:

```
field1|field2|field3
row1|row1|row1
row2|row2|row2
```

The problem I am having is the values returned, it does not let my loop over the whole csv within the second loop. My code is as follows:

```
with open('filepath', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader
    print row[0]
    for crow in reader:
      print crow[11]
```

I cannot print the correct information from row[0] within the second loop.

Comment: note that as you loop through it, you are consuming `reader`. So this code cannot do what you want it to do. `crow` will start from the second line and consume the entire thing, so the outer loop executes only once. Your `print`s do not make much sense either.

Comment: Is there a way I can store the csv without having to read it a second time in the second loop?

Comment: Why do you think you need two loops?

Comment: What are you actually, ultimately trying to accomplish??..

Comment: I have a list of users, each user has a possible manager. I need to loop through finding each user and check if they are the manager of any other users and store those values.

Comment: You'll have to `fseek` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Then upon reading it the first time create a dictionary of `user`-`manager` key-value pairs and process that. Take note of the delimiter the csv is using and make sure the data are read and split correctly by the `csv` module.

Comment: Thank you Ev. Kounis, I'll try that approach instead, this will save on processing time as well.

Comment: You can do `f.seek(0)` before the second loop, to start from the beginning, but then you'll have an issue with your outer loop on the next iteration.